# Firebase billing account and pricing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, account, billing

Consider I have 2 **BLAZE** plan projects in my billing account.

If my project **1** reads **40k** documents in day 1
And my project **2** reads **40k** documents in the same day(day 1)

Is that I will be charged for **80k** reads in my billing account or it will be considered as free since both projects separately read below 50k and Firebase allows **<50k** reads per day for free?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because customer support questions are off-topic

Answer (score 1):

The Firestore quota are per project. Since each project is under its free quota, there'll be no charge.